problem with releasing a flutter application
I tired to release a flutter application using those command of course :
flutter clean flutter pub get flutter build apk --release
and this error occurred:
`You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script '/Users/badriyahaddad/flutter_path/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 343

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.



Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
Could not get unknown property 'usesUnsupportedDependencyVersions' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           96.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1`

So I have tried to clear the gradle cashes but did work
I tried to upgrade the gradle file like : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions ..., or classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:... but also did not work
I tried to upgrade flutter but that's no luck either
I did ask chatGPT 4 but it did help me
in your opinion what should I do ?


Regarding "You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively", that is a warning and you should look at the migration guide https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply. As for your error, can you share what is your gradle version and AGP version?
